# Delete an apostrophe from a file in bash

Tags: bash

Inside a file (menuok.csv), I have a line that contains an apostrophe. I need to delete it and some words. I have others lines with apostrophe, but I don't want to remove them. I am using the following code but it doesn't help

I need to change **Cloïses, Rap i menta de l'hort-Ripoll** for **Ripoll**

```
sed -i s/"Cloïses, Rap i menta de l'hort-Ripoll/Ripoll"/g menuok.csv > menu.csv
```

The encoding of the file menuok.csv is charset=iso-8859-1
In locale, if I check, I get

```
[enric@localhost ~]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Is this different encoding between menuok.csv and locale the source of this problem?

Comment: What is happening instead of success?  Does sed give you an error, or merely skip making the change?  Have you tried applying the substitution to a smaller string as a test, or perhaps avoiding the "special" character in the first word?

Comment: I don't receive an error, only skip making the change

Comment: Which code set is your data encoded in?  UTF-8?  8859-15?  CP1252?  Something else?  Can you use `Clo.ses` in the pattern, risking the metacharacter matching anything (but how many words are there like that).  If that doesn't work, what about `Clo.*ses …`?

Comment: I have typed "file -i menuok.csv"  and I receive   text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: how about `sed -i s/"Cloïses, .*Ripoll/Ripoll"/g menuok.csv` (the `> menu.csv` seems redundant if you're not getting an error message like "don't recognize -i option in sed" . I've replaced a big chunk of your search target, including the special chars, with `.*`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `-i` which changes the input file. Since with this option there is no output, you're not writing anything to `menu.csv`

Check `menuok.csv`, it should have changed there.

If it hasn't, I suspect there is something wrong with the regular expression. It is quite long, and contains some special characters.

Comment: In menuok.csv it has not changed

Comment: If I execute the code with another word without special character like ", it changes.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sed -e "s/Cloïses, Rap i menta de l'hort-Ripoll/Ripoll/g" menuok.csv > menu.csv
```

Comment: Strange. There is no error displayed from sed? Can you try with a single line and post the output that you obtain?

Comment: No error displayed from sed. If I type sed -e "s/Horta de proximitat/Horta/g" menuok.csv , it works. The problem is the encoding...the dieresis over the "i" of Cloïses

Answer (score 0):

> Is this different encoding between menuok.csv and locale the source of
>   this problem?

You suppose right.
If you want to stay with your UTF-8 locale, you have to specify the character `ï` in the pattern differently, e. g. as the ISO-8859-1 code `ef`

```
sed s/"Clo\xefses, Rap i menta de l'hort-Ripoll/Ripoll"/g menuok.csv >menu.csv
```